# Can a button be added to Google Drive (Sheets) toolbar?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Google Drive Sheets for spreadsheet budget management.

I am frequently using the Insert > Row Above/Below menus.

I don't find any shortcut for either menu option in the Keyboard Shortcuts index, nor is there a related toolbar button.

Is there any way to add a toolbar button for this menu item, or to create a keyboard shortcut for this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You can right click (or ctrl-click for Mac) on the number of the row you wish to insert above or below, and select Insert 1 Before or Insert 1 After.

Similarly, you can select *n* number of rows and follow the process above to add *n* rows above or below the cursor.

For the keyboard shortcuts (assuming Google Chrome)

- On a PC: Alt+I, R for above; Alt+I, W for below
- On a Mac: Ctrl-Option-I, R for above; Ctrl-Option-I, W for below.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this! Yes, I'm aware of the right-click context menu. I do not use Google Chrome and so the corresponding Alt+Shift+I R would work, but I was hoping for something more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a button on your own if you want. This is the google script function: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsrowindex-numrows

And here is a script to add a menu item:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus
After you added this script, you need to refresh the document.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this! The scripted button is a nice solution, although slow and embedded within the sheet instead of attached to the Google formatting toolbar, it does work.